# Django query difference in group

Tags: django, django-models

suppose I have a Model A with a one-to-many relationship with Model B which has a one-to-one relationship with Model C. Model C has attribute X which holds a numeric value. This is illustrated below:

[image: models illustration]

What is the best way to express a query where I would want all instances of model A where the attribute X on its related model C's (through model B) have a certain percentage difference among them?

for example:

I want all A's where any of the related model C's X attributes have a difference of 20% or more:

modelA[id=1]

model Bs [A1:B1 ,A1:B2, A1:B3]

model Cs attr x values [A1:B1:C:attrX=> 10, A1:B2:C:attrX=> 14, A1:B3:C:attrX=> 13]

This example would qualify because A1:B1:C:attrX has a 20% or higher difference with at least one other attrX

EDIT 1:

I would also be interested in all Model Cs grouped by B or A, if the other query isn't feasible.

Or even all model Bs grouped by A...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want all A's where any of the related model C's X attributes have a difference of 20% or more

If any of the C.x for A has difference of %20 then surely MAX and MIN C.x for that A has at least %20 or more difference. You can construct your query on that fact. Using [aggregate expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#aggregate-expressions) you can do something like this:

```
A.objects.annotate(
      max_diff=(Max('b__c__x') - Min('b__c__x')) * 100 / Min('b__c__x')
    ).filter(max_diff__gte=20)
```

Of course b, c represents the related names for the foreign or many to many relations. This will first annotate A objects with `max_diff` in percent, then we filter on that value. Depending on your field types you might need to specify an [output_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Aggregate) too.

I don't know the specifics for your problem but I'd also recommend you to check available [aggregation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions), maybe standard deviation or variance would help.

Reference:

- [Django aggregate expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#aggregate-expressions)
- [Django aggregation functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions)
- [Django filtering on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)

Answer (score 0):

This may be doable in the orm, but it sounds like the sort of thing that would be a mess (need to make sure the count of those within 20% of the average of all of them is the same as the count of call of them). It seems like a great opportunity for a prefetch. Maybe something like

```py
for a in A.objects.prefetch_related("b_set__c"):
    cs = [b.c for b in a.b_set.all()]
```

and then you can apply your filtering in python which will make it a little more inspectable and should only run a finite number of queries. The only issue is that your queryset hopefully isn't too large to iterate over entirely for this result.

If this method doesn't work out well, you may be better served by adding a column for indicate whether this fits your low-variability criterion and updating that when saving instances of `B` and `C`.

Comment: There will be about 10M items, which will be updated often. I think an ORM solution which has Postgres do the heavy lifting would be preferable.